# create a script on a windows box that retrieves data from the Linux box by executing cmds

Tags: linux, windows, putty

How can i create a script on a windows box that retrieves data from the Linux box by executing cmds against the remote Linux box?

I have got putty and Plink on the win box but not sure how to fire the cmds from a script eg a bat file and get the results written back to a txt file on the win box.

Any ideas how i would do this for something simple like a grep or LS cmd for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plink on the command line to execute remote commands. Put the remote commands in a file like:

```
ls
cd ~/some/directory
echo "whatever"
```

Then run plink:

```
C:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe -ssh -l <username> -pw <password> <ip/url> -m \your\file\with\the\commands
```

To send the output of plink to a file:

```
(C:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe -ssh -l <username> -pw <password> <ip/url> -m \your\file\with\the\commands) >> logfile.txt 2>>&1
```